# Text based game not updating board

Tags: java, eclipse, text

It's a text based game where the objective is to collect all the gold(total of 4 pieces), and make it to the steps(which unlock after you get all the gold) without getting eaten by the monsters(also 4).

I have classes for the player(Adventurer) the board, the monsters, the steps, and a main method where they all come together. I was off to a great start. The player is able to move around and the cold counter works. Seeing as that worked so I pretty much did the same code for the monster class (minus getting input because they are suppose to move on their own). How the player moves is it makes a string equal to sections of the array that is the map then modify the string and then plug it back into the original map. When I comment out the monster move method the game runs fine, but if I try to implement the monster move method the game starts but wont go pass the initial board and allow the player to move.

[image: Unable to move player image]

**Main method** is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    Map board = new Map();
    STEVE = new Adventurer();
    Monster m1 = new Monster();
    Stairs step = new Stairs();
    do{
        STEVE.finished();

        while(!STEVE.finished()){
            System.out.print(board.toString());
            System.out.println("Current gold held is:"+Adventurer.gold);
            System.out.println("Which direction would you like to move?");
            String dup = scan.nextLine();
            char dir = dup.charAt(0);
            int direction = java.lang.Character.getNumericValue(dir);
            if (direction == W){
                STEVE.move(UP);
            }
            if (direction == S){
                STEVE.move(DOWN);
            }
            if (direction == A){
                STEVE.move(LEFT);
            }
            if (direction == D){
                STEVE.move(RIGHT);
            }
            m1.move();
            //step.isLocked(Adventurer.gold);

            if(STEVE.finished()){
                System.out.print(board.toString());
                System.out.println("Congrats! You beat the game!");
                fin = true;
            }
        }
    }while (!fin);
}
```

**Adventurer move method:**

```
public void move(int direction){
    String[] map = Map.table;
    String money = "$";
    String wall = "*";
    String stairs = "\\";
    char shiny = '$';
    char block = '*';
    char stairz = '\\';
    if(direction == UP){
        String yup = map[getRow()-1];
        if(yup.charAt(getColumn())==(shiny)){
            getGold();
        }
        String up = yup.substring(0, getColumn())+"P"+yup.substring(getColumn()+1);
        if(yup.charAt(getColumn())==(block)){
            up = yup;
            map[getRow()+1]=map[getRow()+1];
        }
        else{
            map[getRow()-1] = up;
            map[getRow()+1] = map[getRow()+1].substring(0, getColumn())+"."+map[getRow()+1].substring(getColumn()+1);
        }
        Map.table = map;
    }
    if(direction == DOWN){
        String yup = map[getRow()+1];
        if(yup.charAt(getColumn())==(shiny)){
            getGold();
        }
        String up = yup.substring(0, getColumn())+"P"+yup.substring(getColumn()+1);
        if(yup.charAt(getColumn())==(block)||yup.charAt(getColumn())==(stairz)){
            up = yup;
            map[getRow()-1]=map[getRow()-1];
        }
        else{
            map[getRow()+1] = up;
            map[getRow()] = map[getRow()].substring(0, getColumn())+"."+map[getRow()].substring(getColumn()+1);
        }
        Map.table = map;
    }
    if(direction == LEFT){
        String yup = map[getRow()];
        if(yup.substring(getColumn()-1, getColumn()).equals(money)){
            getGold();
        }
        String up = yup.substring(0, getColumn()-1)+"P"+"."+yup.substring(getColumn()+1, yup.length());
        if(yup.substring(getColumn()-1, getColumn()).equals(wall)){
            up=yup;
        }
        map[getRow()] = up;
        Map.table = map;
    }
    if(direction == RIGHT){
        String yup = map[getRow()];
        if(yup.substring(getColumn()+1, getColumn()+DOWN).equals(money)){
        getGold();
        }
        String up = yup.substring(0, getColumn())+"."+"P"+yup.substring(getColumn()+DOWN, yup.length());
        if(yup.substring(getColumn()+1, getColumn()+DOWN).equals(wall)||yup.substring(getColumn()+1, getColumn()+DOWN).equals(stairs)){
            up=yup;
        }
        map[getRow()] = up;
        Map.table = map;
    }
}
```

**Monster move method:**

```
public void move(){
    String[] map = Map.table;
    String mon=map[row1].substring(col1, col1+1);
    int counter = 1;

    while(counter<FIVE){
        if(counter==1){
            if(mon.equals("^")){
                String up = map[row1-1];
                String cur = map[row1];
                up=up.substring(0, col1)+"^"+up.substring(col1+1);
                cur=cur.substring(0, col1)+"."+cur.substring(col1+1);
                map[row1-1]=up;
                map[row1]=cur;
                mon=map[row2].substring(col2, col2+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=2;
            }
            else if(mon.equals("v")){
                String down = map[row1+1];
                String cur = map[row1];
                down = down.substring(0, col1)+"v"+down.substring(col1+1);
                cur =cur.substring(0, col1)+"."+cur.substring(col1+1);
                map[row1+1]=down;
                map[row1]=cur;
                mon=map[row2].substring(col2, col2+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=2;   
            }
            else if(mon.equals("<")){
                String left = map[row1];
                left = left.substring(0, col1-1)+"<"+"."+left.substring(col1+1);
                map[row1]=left;
                mon=map[row2].substring(col2, col2+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=2;          
            }
            else if(mon.equals(">")){
                String right = map[row1];
                String fix = "";
                fix = right.substring(0, col1)+"."+">"+right.substring(col1+OFFSET, right.length());
                map[row1]=fix;
                mon=map[row2].substring(col2, col2+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter = 2;
            }
        }

        if(counter==2){
            if(mon.equals("^")){
                String up = map[row2-1];
                String cur = map[row2];
                up=up.substring(0, col2)+"^"+up.substring(col2+1);
                cur=cur.substring(0, col2)+"."+cur.substring(col2+1);
                map[row2-1]=up;
                map[row2]=cur;
                mon=map[row3].substring(col3, col3+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=3;
            }
            else if(mon.equals("v")){
                String down = map[row2+1];
                String cur = map[row2];
                down = down.substring(0, col2)+"v"+down.substring(col2+1);
                cur =cur.substring(0, col2)+"."+cur.substring(col2+1);
                map[row2+1]=down;
                map[row2]=cur;
                mon=map[row3].substring(col3, col3+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=3;   
            }
            else if(mon.equals("<")){
                String left = map[row2];
                left = left.substring(0, col2-1)+"<"+"."+left.substring(col2+1);
                map[row2]=left;
                mon=map[row3].substring(col3, col3+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=3;          
            }
            else if(mon.equals(">")){
                String right = map[row2];
                String fix = "";
                fix = right.substring(0, col2)+"."+">"+right.substring(col2+OFFSET, right.length());
                map[row2]=fix;
                mon=map[row3].substring(col3, col3+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter = 3;
            }
        }

        if(counter==3){
            if(mon.equals("^")){
                String up = map[row3-1];
                String cur = map[row3];
                up=up.substring(0, col3)+"^"+up.substring(col3+1);
                cur=cur.substring(0, col3)+"."+cur.substring(col3+1);
                map[row3-1]=up;
                map[row3]=cur;
                mon=map[row4].substring(col4, col4+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=4;
            }
            else if(mon.equals("v")){
                String down = map[row3+1];
                String cur = map[row3];
                down = down.substring(0, col3)+"v"+down.substring(col3+1);
                cur =cur.substring(0, col3)+"."+cur.substring(col3+1);
                map[row3+1]=down;
                map[row3]=cur;
                mon=map[row4].substring(col4, col4+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=4;   
            }
            else if(mon.equals("<")){
                String left = map[row3];
                left = left.substring(0, col3-1)+"<"+"."+left.substring(col3+1);
                map[row3]=left;
                mon=map[row4].substring(col4, col4+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter=4;          
            }
            else if(mon.equals(">")){
                String right = map[row3];
                String fix = "";
                fix = right.substring(0, col3)+"."+">"+right.substring(col3+OFFSET, right.length());
                map[row3]=fix;
                mon=map[row4].substring(col4, col4+1);
                Map.table = map;
                counter = 4;
            }
        }

        if(counter==4){
            if(mon.equals("^")){
                String up = map[row4-1];
                String cur = map[row4];
                up=up.substring(0, col4)+"^"+up.substring(col4+1);
                cur=cur.substring(0, col4)+"."+cur.substring(col4+1);
                map[row4-1]=up;
                map[row4]=cur;
                Map.table = map;
                counter=5;
            }
            else if(mon.equals("v")){
                String down = map[row4+1];
                String cur = map[row4];
                down = down.substring(0, col4)+"v"+down.substring(col4+1);
                cur =cur.substring(0, col4)+"."+cur.substring(col4+1);
                map[row4+1]=down;
                map[row4]=cur;
                Map.table = map;
                counter=5;   
            }
            else if(mon.equals("<")){
                String left = map[row4];
                left = left.substring(0, col4-1)+"<"+"."+left.substring(col4+1);
                map[row4]=left;
                Map.table = map;
                counter=5;          
            }
            else if(mon.equals(">")){
                String right = map[row4];
                String fix = "";
                fix = right.substring(0, col4)+"."+">"+right.substring(col4+OFFSET, right.length());
                map[row4]=fix;
                Map.table = map;
                counter = 5;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the reason the monsters' is so long is because there are 4 of them and they move based upon the direction they are facing and if they see the player. And finall the board/map:

```
public static String[] table= {
        "....................",
        "....................",
        "....P...............",
        "....................",
        "....................",
        "......*******.......",
        "......*.............",
        "......*.............",
        "......*.....>.......",
        "......*.............",
        ".....<..............",
        ".$....^.............",
        "....................",
        "....................",
        "....................",
        "......*.............",
        "...$..*..........$..",
        "......***...........",
        ".............<......",
        "................$..\\"};
```

sorry for long post but I believe everything I included is necessary. the asterisks(*) are walls if you care.

Comment: What are the values of `row1` and `col1`? What is there at that coordinate when you first call the monster move?

Comment: row1 is the array element where the first monster ">" can be found(8). col1 is its index in the string (12).

Comment: Based on your description it sounds like Monster.move() is infinitely looping.  Looking at the while loop, not all logic paths are accounted for (all else ifs, and no final else), which may mean that counter never reaches 5.  Best way to tell is to debug into it and step line by line to see where its getting stuck.